# Room vs Active Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room, activeandroid

Recently google announced Room library to facilitate android local database storage implementation. Since I already used Active Android in my previous project, couldn't understand the advantages of Room over Active android. In fact implementation wise I felt Active Android is easier. Someone explain differences between Google's Room and Active Android? Which one is better in performance wise?

Thanks in advance